# Iteratively create a lambda expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to create a list that includes a lambda expression where this lambda expression is supposed to compute something with respect to the input value and the value within itself. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```py
collection = []
for i in range(5):
    collection.append(lambda x: x+i)
```

If I execute each lambda expression with the same value, I would expect different outcomes since `i` are supposed to be different, but I always get the same result.

```py
for f in collection:
    print(f(0))
4
4
4
4
4
```

I tried to wrap `i` with `copy.deepcopy(i)`; however, this didn't work as well. Is there a way to fix the value of `i` once it's included in the lambda expression?